# How to run for loop over SSH on remote so that variables expand?

Tags: bash, ssh, for

If I `ls` files without a for loop in a remote host everything is fine however, if I capture the `ls` in a variable and try to `echo` each file it fails as the variables don't expand/have a value.

What I mean:

```bash
IFS=$'\n'
servers=(
  blue
  green
  red
)
```

```bash
for i in ${servers[@]}; do 
   ssh $i "
     ls /dir/xyz_${i}*/details.txt
   "
done
/dir/xyx_blue0/details.txt 
/dir/xyz_blue1/details.txt
/dir/xyx_green2/details.txt 
/dir/xyz_green4/details.txt
/dir/xyx_red1/details.txt 
/dir/xyz_red8/details.txt
```

But I actually need to loop through the output of `ls` so I can do things to the files, however the variable doesn't expand:

```bash
for i in ${servers[@]}; do 
   ssh $i "
     for i in $(ls /dir/xyz_${i}*/details.txt); do 
        echo $i
     done
   "
done
not found: /dir/xyx_blue*/details.txt 
not found: /dir/xyx_green*/details.txt 
not found: /dir/xyx_red*/details.txt
```

How can I get `$i` to expand when running a loop on the remote host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the command substitution that you want to run on the remote servers is run locally.  This is due to the substitution occurring within double quotes, meaning the local shell will compute its expansion before calling `ssh`.

Also, reading the output of `ls` is ill-advised (see [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)).

Instead:

```bash
servers=(
  blue
  green
  red
)

for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
    ssh -T "$server" <<END_SCRIPT
shopt -s nullglob
for pathname in /dir/xyz_$server*/details.txt; do
    printf 'file path is "%s"\n' "\$pathname"
done
END_SCRIPT
done
```

This uses an unquoted "here-document" as the script that is sent to the remote servers.  The script first sets the `nullglob` shell option (this is assuming that the remote shell is `bash`) to avoid looping at all in the inner loop if the pattern does not match any filenames.  It then iterates over the pattern `/dir/xyz_$server*/details.txt` where `$server` will be substituted with the current server name.

The loop then prints out a short message about what filenames matched the pattern, and the code ensures that the `$pathname` variable is not expanded by the *local* shell by escaping the `$`.

Note that `$` in `$server` is unescaped and will therefore be expanded by the local shell, which is what we want, but that `$` in `$pathname` needs to be escaped to *supress* the local expansion.

We don't need to set `IFS` to anything non-default. I'm assuming you did that to be able to write the array assignment as you did, or for some other reason, but none of the code above needs that.

I'm using `-T` with `ssh` to explicitly turn off pseudo-TTY allocation.

---

You *could* also provide the script as a single string if you feel that this is somehow needed:

```bash
servers=(
  blue
  green
  red
)

for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
    ssh "$server" "
shopt -s nullglob
for pathname in /dir/xyz_$server*/details.txt; do
    printf 'file path is \"%s\"\n' \"\$pathname\"
done"
done
```

In this case, you must additionally ensure that each embedded double quote is escaped (or they would end the double-quoted string that constitutes the remote shell script).

Comment: the `ls` example was stupid by me... I'm ssh'ing to various servers then parsing the multitude of 'red', 'green', 'blue' files. For that I need to capture output in variables using `$()`, but that doesn't work, also I'm having to escape variables for them to show like `\$var` and I'm using functions defined locally, I'll try your answer but thought I'd leave this question if you answer applies to my case.

Comment: I set IFS as so, so I don't need to quote everything (only split words on newline not spaces).

Comment: how can I get command substitution to occur on the remote server? Escaping doesn't work.

Comment: @Nickotine A command substitution would be left unexpanded locally if you escape its `$`, as in `\$(some-command)`.

Comment: @Nickotine Also note that we can't help you with code that you do not show.

Comment: the problem is when saving $() to a variable like `x=$(cmd file)` then `echo $x` returns nothing

Comment: I think I should ask another question since I just figured out my real issue.

Answer (score 0):

Never `for`-loop over the output of `ls`; that's literally what `*` globbing is for, and your whole usage of `ls` is totally superfluous.

That solves the whole problem, honestly, because you're currently running the `$(…)` locally instead of on the target host.

Comment: thanks but I have the same issue. The variable from the first loop is not getting expanded in the second loop.

Comment: so my real issue is trying to get command substitution to occur on the remote, in the loop I have many $() saved to variables.